# Adding a Path to Directory Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, c, windows, netbeans

I am configuring the cygwin (c/c++) compiler and tools for the netbeans 8.02 IDE I installed.

I have successfully installed netbeans with the c/c++ plugin. All I need now is to set up the c/c++ compiler and tools.

I went to cygwin.com, ran the setup-x86 64.exe and it installed successfully. There is one last step for me to properly configure c/c++ compiler and tools with the netbeans IDE.

THE LAST STEP:
- the last step is to add the directory where the cygwin folder is located to the path in the Environment Variables in Windows.

So to do this I followed these steps:

1. open control panel
2. type var in search tool
3. click "Edit The System Environment Variables"
4. click on Advanced Tab
5. click Environment Variables
6. Underneath "User variables for Owner" I highlight PATH
7. I select the edit button

... okay this is where I get stuck

Inside the Edit User Variable Box I see this path:

C:\User\Ownder\AppData\Roaming\npm

... and I dont know how to add the cygwin directory to his path.

I tried this:

C:User\Ownder\AppData\Roaming\npm; C:\cygwin\bin

but that didn't seem to change anything in Netbeans.

I also saw on google that there is a setx command I could use in the cmd window but I haven't tried that yet. I want to see if any of yous can help me find a solution.

Thanks guys in advance and I really appreciate your help

:)

Answer (score 0):

You should Restart your machine and then check. your process is right it should work.

Comment: Thank you @Fahim_Sharier_Rasel.