# Spyder does not find glpsol

Tags: python, macos, spyder, glpk, pyomo

I use os x 10.11, anaconda 1.3.1, python 3.5, glpk 4.60, pyomo 5.0.1, spyder 3.0.2. 
If i run a scrip which uses pyomo to call glpk i get the following warning and error:

```
WARNING:pyomo.solvers:Could not locate the 'glpsol' executable, which is required for solver 'glpk'
ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'glpk'
```

If i start the same script via the terminal or a jupyter notebook it runs without a problem.

I installed glpk using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge glpk=4.60
```

How do i get glpk working within the spyder environement?

If i run

```
which glpsol
```

i get

```
/Users/myusername/anaconda/bin/glpsol
```

but adding the directory into the PYTHONPATH manager within Spyder does not change anything.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please start Spyder from a terminal and try again. That could help.

Comment: Thanks this helped and solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Pyomo's GLPK interface works by launching `glpsol` as a separate process.  It finds the `glpsol` executable by searching the `PATH` environment variable.  You need to make sure that the path to `glpsol` (in your case `/Users/myusername/anaconda/bin/`) is in the `PATH` environment variable for the spyder environment.  You can do this in a number of ways:

- [Windows only] it is possible to edit this using `Tools`-`Current user environment variables` in the spyder IDE.
- [Windows only] you can set your user's PATH within Windows (the route to the option varies from version to version, for example, see [Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400030/windows-7-add-path) or [Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662478/adding-a-path-to-directory-windows-8-1).
- [Unix/Linux/MacOS] you can edit your shell initialization (e.g., `~/.bashrc` for BASH, `~/.cshrc` for CSH/TCSH) to set the `PATH` environment variable there.
- [within Spyder] you can specify either a couple lines of python code or a small script that adds the directory to the IPython console PATH through the spyder preferences (`Tools`-`Preferences`-`IPython console`-`Startup` tab.  You would want something like:

  ```
  import os
  os.environ['PATH'] = os.pathsep.join((os.environ['PATH'], '/Users/myusername/anaconda/bin/'))
  ```

Note: `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` are not the same: `PATH` is the executable search path.  `PYTHONPATH` is the search path that Python uses to find importable modules.

Comment: This suggestion does not work for me if I start spyder from the anaconda navigator. But it seems to be a problem of the navigator itself. If i start spyder from the terminal (as Carlos suggested in the comment) the PATH variable seems to have the path to glpsol.